# Shading Issue after smoothing

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, shadows

I have a shading problem but I don't know how to fix it. I dont have enough experience to fix it alone so can somebody give me a tip.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file : https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've shade smoothed, it tries to smooth between these faces and some adjacent ones, if you decrease the *Auto Smooth* angle, it will fix your problem (and keep the smooth where you want it to happen):

[image]